# OnItemClick of list view it should show the detialFragment with swipeable functionality in ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipeview

In brief, I am going to build a Project with swipeView and the fragments.

1. MainActivity.java
   a. ListViewFragment.java
   b. DetialFragment1.java
   c. DetialFragment3.java
   d. DetialFragment4.java
   e. DetialFragment5.java

MainActivity.java contain the swipeView layout with all other fragments mentioned above. When I first open my app it display the listView fragment of the swipeView. And onSwipe the fragments are swipe one by one which is okey. But I also want .. when I click the fragment listView onItem 4 , It should directly show DetialFragment4 with the capability to swipe other fragments. PLEASE HELP....

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer. I'm sorry but this time stackoverflow is lil bit slow... waiting and waiting with no answer. And now, I found answer ..

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public static void getViewPagerAtCurrentPosition(int position)
 {
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
 }
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        MainActivity.getViewPagerAtCurrentPosition(1);
        break;
    case 1:
        MainActivity.getViewPagerAtCurrentPosition(2);
        break;
    case 2:
        MainActivity.getViewPagerAtCurrentPosition(3);
        break;
    case 3:
        MainActivity.getViewPagerAtCurrentPosition(4);
        break;
}
```